# How to phrase this sentence about showing fingers?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

> A took **B**'s hand & shows **B**'s four fingers to **B** & asks **B**
>   How many fingers does **B** see.

I mentioned **B** about five times in above sentence, Is it possible to mention **B** only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the same **tense** in each part of the sentence.

You could use two different sentences (let's assume B is a boy, for example) using *direct object pronouns*:

> A **took** B's hand, **showed** *him* his four fingers, and **asked** *him* how many he **saw**.
>
> A **takes** B's hand, **shows** *him* his four fingers, and **asks** *him* how many he **sees**.